# Unable to structure and read data from include_vars file in Ansible

Tags: file, variables, ansible

I get the checksum and mode (permissions) of a file on a server IP using ansible's stat module.

I have generated a variable file which stores the past file information like below:

```
cat gc.yaml
---
10.9.9.112:
  name: 
    - /tmp/conf/httpd.conf
    - /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
  hash: 
    - 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s7
    - 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t
  mode: 
    - 0754
    - 0755    
10.9.9.114:
  name: 
    - /was/conf/httpd.conf
    - /was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
  hash: 
    - 5r5r5r5r5r5r5r5r
    - 2o2o2o2o2o2o2o2
  mode: 
    - 0754
    - 0750
```

Is this the correct way to design the variable file? Under the IP I have a duplicate name, mode, and checksum one for httpd.conf and other httpd-ssl.conf. I'm not sure if this is the correct structure. Kindly propose to incase this will not work and I can design the gc.yaml accordingly.

My requirement is to check if the current play's stat for a particular file matches the one in the gc.yaml

My playbook looks like below:

```
ansible-playbook /app/test.yml -e files_list="/tmp/conf/httpd.conf,/tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"

  tasks:

   - name: Get stat of the files from `{{ inventory_hostname }}`
     stat:
       path: "{{ item }}"
     register: files_det
     with_items: "{{ files_list.split(',') }}"

   - debug:
       msg: "HERE IS CKSUM_{{ item.stat.checksum }}.HERE IS MODE_{{ item.stat.mode }}"
     with_items: "{{ files_det.results }}"
```

Below is where i wish read corresponding data from gc.yaml and compare with the files_det variable however, I'm not sure how to read the gc.yaml data

```
   - include_vars:
       file="{{ playbook_dir }}/gc.yaml"
       name=user1

   - debug: var=user1

   - debug:
       msg: "HERE IS THE NAME:{{ item }}"
     with_dict: 10.9.9.112

   - debug:
       msg: "HERE IS THE NAME:{{ item }}.name  HERE is the VALUE:{{ item }}.hash"
     with_dict: "{{ user1 }}"
```

Given an iP address, how can we get mode and checksum for each file?

Kindly suggest?

Comment: Any suggestions / solutions anyone ?

Comment: I'm not really clear what you're trying to do.  But do note that you cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary...maybe you want to use a list?

Comment: @larsks I guess this format is what you are suggesting for my include_vars gc.yml

`---
10.9.9.112:
   name: '["/tmp/conf/httpd.conf", "/tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"]'
   hash: '["8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s", "7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t"]'
   mode: '["0754", "0755"]

10.9.9.114:
   name: '["/was/conf/httpd.conf", "/was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"]'
   hash: '["5r5r5r5r5r5r5r5r", "2o2o2o2o2o2o2o2"]'
   mode: '["0754", "0750"]'`

Can you still guide me on how can I read the hash for a particular file say /was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf for IP 10.9.9.114 inside my play ?

Comment: @larsks I updated my original post with your suggestion. Can you still guide me on how can I read the hash for a particular file say /was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf for IP 10.9.9.114 inside my play ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish, so I'm making a few assumptions here.  I think you'll find things easiest if you restructure your `gc.yaml` file so that it looks like this:

```
---
hosts:
  - host: 10.9.9.112
    files:
       - name: /tmp/conf/httpd.conf
         hash: 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s
         mode: 0754
       - name: /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
         hash: 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t
         mode: 0755

  - host: 10.9.9.114
    files:
       - name: /was/conf/httpd.conf
         hash: 5r5r5r5r5r5r5r5r
         mode: 0754
       - name: /was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
         hash: 2o2o2o2o2o2o2o2
         mode: 0750
```

We have a top level `hosts` key whose value is a list. Each list item is a dictionary with a `host` key that has a hostname, and a `files` key that has a list of files.

This structure makes the data useful with Ansible's [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements) filter.

For example, given the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Enable Site
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gc.yaml"
        name: user1

    - debug:
        msg: "file {{ item.1.name }} on host {{ item.0.host }} has hash {{ item.1.hash }}"
      loop: "{{ user1.hosts|subelements('files') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.host }}:{{ item.1.name }}"
```

We get the following output:

```
PLAY [Enable Site] *******************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.9.9.112:/tmp/conf/httpd.conf) => {
    "msg": "file /tmp/conf/httpd.conf on host 10.9.9.112 has hash 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.9.9.112:/tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf) => {
    "msg": "file /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf on host 10.9.9.112 has hash 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.9.9.114:/was/conf/httpd.conf) => {
    "msg": "file /was/conf/httpd.conf on host 10.9.9.114 has hash 5r5r5r5r5r5r5r5r"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.9.9.114:/was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf) => {
    "msg": "file /was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf on host 10.9.9.114 has hash 2o2o2o2o2o2o2o2"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

The `subelements` filter provides our loop with a list of tuples such that the first item of the tuple iterates through the items of the `hosts` list, and the second item iterates through the items in the `files` list for the current host.

That is, the first time we iterate through the loop, `item` contains:

```
- host: 10.9.9.12
  files:
    - name: /tmp/conf/httpd.conf
      hash: 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s
      mode: 0754
    - name: /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
      hash: 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t
      mode: 0755
- name: /tmp/conf/httpd.conf
  hash: 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s
  mode: 0754
```

And the second time:

```
- host: 10.9.9.12
  files:
    - name: /tmp/conf/httpd.conf
      hash: 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s
      mode: 0754
    - name: /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
      hash: 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t
      mode: 0755
- name: /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
  hash: 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t
  mode: 0755
```

And so on.

---

If you're not going to be looping over the data, but instead want to be able to get the hash of a file given a filename, then structure your data like this instead:

```
---
10.9.9.112:
   /tmp/conf/httpd.conf:
     hash: 8g8gf8d8d8ds8s8s
     mode: 0754
   /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
     hash: 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t
     mode: 0755

10.9.9.114:
   /was/conf/httpd.conf:
     hash: 5r5r5r5r5r5r5r5r
     mode: 0754
   /was/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
     hash: 2o2o2o2o2o2o2o2
     mode: 0750
```

Now your filenames are dictionary keys, so you can ask for `user1[<host>][<filename>]`, like this:

```
---
- name: Enable Site
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gc.yaml"
        name: user1

    - debug:
        msg: "file {{ item.file }} on host {{ item.host }} has hash {{ user1[item.host][item.file].hash }}"
      loop:
        - host: 10.9.9.112
          file: /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

The above results in:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'host': '10.9.9.112', 'file': '/tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf'}) => {
    "msg": "file /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf on host 10.9.9.112 has hash 7t7t7t7t7t7t7t7t"
}
```

Comment: This works but rather than looping (without looping) how can i directly get the details of the files given the ip address? Thus rather than looping all items how can i get the hash of a particular file say hash of /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf on 10.9.9.12

Comment: I've updated the answer to show an example of directly accessing a hash like that.